# Can't install APK with getFilesDir() from KitKat to Marshmallow WHY?

Tags: android, android-file, android-storage

I was trying to install an APK File by using `getFilesDir()` because i wanted to put it in the internal storage.

but it only didn't work in Kitkat, Lollipop and Marshmallow and i couldn't install the APK. So i replaced `getFilesDir()` with `getExternalFilesDir()`. And then, it worked well. WHY?

Comment: getFilesDir() will not install an apk. It gives a File instance for a directory.

Comment: @blackapps Then why does it work well over Android 7 Nougat (API 24)...?

Comment: getFilesDir() works well always by returning a File instance for a directory. For the rest it does nothing. getExternalFilesDir() will not install an apk either as it returns a File instance too.